# Playing background sound across pages

Tags: jquery, audio, background

I hope you are doing fine?

I'm trying to play different audio tags depending on user navigation. The code is working as expected on Android phones and tablets and all modern browsers on a computer but not on iOS.

I have an HTML page with 3 audio tags:

```
<audio id="sound1" src="story_content/WebObjects/61H0uJPbrS5/sound_1.mp3" loop=""></audio>
<audio id="sound2" src="story_content/WebObjects/61H0uJPbrS5/sound_2.mp3" loop=""></audio>
<audio id="sound3" src="story_content/WebObjects/61H0uJPbrS5/sound_3.mp3" loop=""></audio>
```

Here is the jquery part. The variable 'slaudio' is set when a page change is triggered by the user:

```
$('audio').each(function() {
    if (typeof this.origvolume !== 'undefined') {
        this.pause();
        this.currentTime = 0;
    }
});

if ($("audio[id='" + slaudio + "']").length > 0) {
    $("audio[id='" + slaudio + "']")[0].play();
}
```

Any idea why, `<audio id="sound2">` and `<audio id="sound3">` are not fired on iPhone and iPad only?
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having multiple audio elements, I change the approach to change the source of it:

```
$('audio').each(function() {
    if (typeof this.volume !== 'undefined') {
        this.pause();
        this.currentTime = 0;
    }
});

if (slaudio === 'sound1') {
    audio_src = web + 'sound_1.mp3';
} else if (slaudio === 'sound2') {
    audio_src = web + 'sound_2.mp3';
} else if (slaudio === 'sound3') {
    audio_src = web + 'sound_3.mp3';
}

$('audio').attr('src', audio_src);
$('audio')[0].play();
```